Is it possible to get accounts using wagmi library?
This is using avalanche's core wallet. You see here I have a few accounts.
Now, using the wagmi library, I can get the address of the currently selected account, but I can't seem to find out how I can get the other accounts.
 const account = useAccount()

There is account.addresses, however, it always returns [address1], there is always one address.

